# convert scientific notations to numbers in Crystal report

Tags: type-conversion, crystal-reports, exponential

I have a running total field which has more than 15 characters and it's returning value in scientific notations.

Is there any way in SAP Crystal reports to convert scientific notations like 1.11e+017 to numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

Please write formula like follow. I tried and It works for me.

```
Local StringVar Array x;
Local StringVar mantissa;
Local StringVar exponent := "0";

// Split into mantissa and exponent parts.
x:= Split("24.2233E+2", "e", 2, 1); // pass column name 
mantissa := x[1];

If (UBound(x) = 2) 
Then
    exponent := x[2];

// CDbl cannot interpret leading positive sign, so removie
If Left(mantissa, 1) = "+" 
Then
    mantissa := Right(mantissa, Length(mantissa) - 1);

If Left(exponent, 1) = "+" 
Then
    exponent := Right(exponent, Length(exponent) - 1);

// Compute number
CDbl(mantissa) * 10 ^ CDbl(exponent);
```

Source : [Converting scientific notation string to number](https://answers.sap.com/questions/4272539/converting-scientific-notation-string-to-number.html)

Comment: Not working in Crystal report, still getting exponential valuea